# How can 2 > 10 be true in PHP?

Tags: php, debugging, operators

I am now staring at my code:

```
if(2 > 10) echo "$#@$#$#$";
```

and the results are that the string is echoed on the page!
So how can this be possible?

If I do this:

```
$i = 2;
$j = 10;
if($i > $j) echo "$#@$#$#$";
```

my script generates a 500 error.

And if I do this:

```
$i = 2;
if($i > 10) echo "$#@$#$#$";
```

I get this error message:

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant  10 - assumed ' 10'
```

What could be the reason for this behavior?

Comment: Sounds like you have a weird space character somewhere. Is that possible?

Comment: What encoding do you use to save the php file?

Comment: Aye, you must have some problem with the character set.  That code is entirely valid, though personally I do not like `if` without a block (`{}`).

Comment: Don't cry! World did not turned upside down. 2 is still < 10 : http://ideone.com/LpIeQ Probably your interpreter is broken or something... Try re-install `PHP`

Comment: Do you actually get "Notice: Use of undefined constant 10 - assumed ' 10'"- notice the whitespace before '10'. It is important to know if this is actually the notice you get.

Comment: The encoding of all my page is UTF-8...

Comment: yes with a white space before

Comment: Ａｒｅ　ｙｏｕ　ｐｏｓｓｉｂｌｙ　ｔｙｐｉｎｇ　ｉｎ　ｆｕｌｌ−ｗｉｄｔｈ　ｃｈａｒａｃｔｅｒｓ，　ｏｒ　ｓｏｍｅｔｈｉｎｇ　ｔｏ　ｔｈａｔ　ｅｘｔｅｎｄ？

Comment: try recoding using another encoding, maybe UTF-8 without BOM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Will probably works fine :

```
if(2 >10) echo "$#@$#$#$";
```

You may have an encoded whitespace you cannot see before 10 (wich is why it's saying assumed ' 10' and not '10')

Comment: well this is working!! How can the space break my script i always do that...?

Comment: @Kaptnkill: Try copy/pasting a space from some other application in the script. Or if possible, try a different editor.

Comment: Well now i can put back my spaces and everything is ok...Thanks again!